JOIN two dataset adding 1 column in SAQL
I am quite new in salesforce SAQL and I'm wondering how to combine in the simplest way two dataset with the following logic.
I have D1 with almost 10 columns. All are important and one of them has codes (D1_codes = A001, A002, A003...).
The second dataset, called D2, has only 2 columns: the first is equal to D1_codes (D2_codes = A001, A002, A003...), and the second one is a map (D2_map = 'problem 1', 'problem 2', 'problem 3'.
All I want is just add D2_map to my first dataset. After that, I have to do more operations on dates and case-when formula. I have not to aggregate, I have just to add this column.
Is there a simply way? In all programming language is a very simple thing.
Thanks to everyone.
